# How can I add a row to a table with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a table following below:

```
<table id="users">
            <tr>
                <td>Row Number</td>
                <td>Name and Surname</td>
                <td>Apartment number</td>
                <td> Status </td>
                <td> E- mail</td>
                <td> Rent Debt</td>
                <td>Edit User</td>
                <td>Send Mail</td>
                <td>Remove User</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

and I want to add following row 10 times to the table:

```
<tr id="myRow">
                <td id="rowNumber" align="center"> </td>
                <td id="name" align="center"></td>
                <td id="aptNumber" align="center"></td>
                <td id="status" align="center"></td>
                <td id="mailAddress"></td>
                <td id="rentDebt" align="center"></td>
                <td id="editButton" align="center"></td>
                <td id="mailButton" align="center"></td>
                <td id="removeButton" align="center"></td>
            </tr>
```

How can I do this with JavaScript? I tried to use loop but I did not manage to do this.

Comment: id's should be unique

Comment: "_I tried to use loop_" Where is that code? What exactly didn't work?

Comment: Please [do a simple search before asking a question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=is%3Aq+%5Bjavascript%5D+How+can+I+add+a+row+to+a+table+with+JavaScript%3F).

Comment: @HereticMonkey I'm new at this platform, thank you for your warning.

Answer (score 1):

Try this with javascript:

```
document.getElementById('users').innerHTML += `<tr id="myRow">
                    <td id="rowNumber" align="center"> </td>
                    <td id="name" align="center"></td>
                    <td id="aptNumber" align="center"></td>
                    <td id="status" align="center"></td>
                    <td id="mailAddress"></td>
                    <td id="rentDebt" align="center"></td>
                    <td id="editButton" align="center"></td>
                    <td id="mailButton" align="center"></td>
                    <td id="removeButton" align="center"></td>
                </tr>`;
```

But your ids should be unique when you will add it multiple time

Comment: Yes ıt must be unique,but ı dont know how can ı do that.Because the row count may change.For example ı have 20 users then there must be 20 rows.

Comment: Try generating uniqe id based on for loop counter or simply by Date.now()